# TSQL Inserting values based on integer results from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running the following query:

```
select
    max(count) Max
from
    (select 
         count(iStockID) Count
     from   
         _etblInvJrBatchLines
     group by 
         iStockID) X
```

As you know, the result of this is an integer; in this case, the result was 5.

Based on the above result, I need to insert generic values into another table, that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO _etblInvJrBatches 
(
    cInvJrNumber            --  IJ0001      Plus 1
,   cInvJrDescription       --  Inventory Journal Batch
,   cInvJrReference         --  IJR10001    Plus 1
,   iCreateAgentID          --  1
,   bClearAfterPost         --  1
,   bAllowDupRef            --  1
,   bAllowEditGLContra      --  0
,   iNewLineDateOpt         --  0
,   iNewLineRefOpt          --  0
,   cNewLineRefDef          --  ''
,   bNewLineRefInc          --  0
,   iNewLineDescOpt         --  0
,   cNewLineDescDef         --  ''
,   bNewLineDescInc         --  0
,   iNewLineProjectOpt      --  0
,   iNewLineProjectDefID    --  0
,   iNewLineWarehouseOpt    --  0
,   iNewLineWarehouseDefID  --  0
,   bJustCleared            --  0
,   iTransactionCode        --  31 (select TrCodeID where TrCode = 'ADJ')
)
SELECT 
    'IJ000'             --  Plus 1
,   'Inventory Journal Batch'
,   'IJR1000'               --  Plus 1
,   1
,   1
,   1
,   0
,   0
,   0
,   ''
,   0
,   0
,   ''
,   0
,   0
,   0
,   0
,   0
,   0
,   (select idTrCodes from TrCodes where Code = 'ADJ')
```

The only problem is, it only inserts this once.

How do I insert this 5 times based on the results I get from my first select statement?

In other words, if the integer result is 24, it needs to import / insert the above 24 times.

Thank you for assisting.

Attie.

Comment: literally the same row, 24 times? I just want to make sure you want the same values, 24 times. Or, is the "plus 1" comment meaning to add 1 up to the max from the subquery. Also, you tagged 3 different versions of sql server. I removed them all, please add only the one that matters.

Comment: Thank you @scsimon! Yeah, just the same value 24 times. The Plus 1 was just for my own reference - (To add a counter on the end of that field later). See my response to Thomas, his advise assisted a lot! Thanks again!

Comment: Aside: If this is something you are doing from SSMS as a one-time thing you can use the curious `count` argument on the [`GO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017) command to repeat the statement (batch) multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant you just use a tally table?

```
declare @count int



 set @count = (select
    max(count) Max
from
    (select 
         count(iStockID) Count
     from   
         _etblInvJrBatchLines
     group by 
         iStockID) X) --Hardcoded 10
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tally') IS NOT NULL
  /*Then it exists*/
  DROP TABLE #tally
SELECT TOP (@count) --equates to more than 30 years of dates
        IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS N
   INTO #tally
   FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns sc1,
        Master.dbo.SysColumns sc2

--PRINT @count
INSERT INTO  _etblInvJrBatches 
(
    cInvJrNumber            --  IJ0001      Plus 1
,   cInvJrDescription       --  Inventory Journal Batch
,   cInvJrReference         --  IJR10001    Plus 1
,   iCreateAgentID          --  1
,   bClearAfterPost         --  1
,   bAllowDupRef            --  1
,   bAllowEditGLContra      --  0
,   iNewLineDateOpt         --  0
,   iNewLineRefOpt          --  0
,   cNewLineRefDef          --  ''
,   bNewLineRefInc          --  0
,   iNewLineDescOpt         --  0
,   cNewLineDescDef         --  ''
,   bNewLineDescInc         --  0
,   iNewLineProjectOpt      --  0
,   iNewLineProjectDefID    --  0
,   iNewLineWarehouseOpt    --  0
,   iNewLineWarehouseDefID  --  0
,   bJustCleared            --  0
,   iTransactionCode        --  31 (select TrCodeID where TrCode = 'ADJ')
)


select N,    'IJ000'             --  Plus 1
,   'Inventory Journal Batch'
,   'IJR1000'               --  Plus 1
,   1
,   1
,   1
,   0
,   0
,   0
,   ''
,   0
,   0
,   ''
,   0
,   0
,   0
,   0
,   0
,   0 from #tally where n >0 and n <= @count
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Thomas! This one works like a charm, I just changed it a bit to my advantage for it to work in my environment. Thanks!

Comment: @Birel Glad i could help - Remember to mark it as the correct answer so others can benefit from it. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this.
INSERT only inserts one row into the target table. Ultimately you are going to have to INSERT in a loop.

Possible solutions...

Do the looping in the database...

```
declare @count int = (select
    max(count) Max
from
    (select 
         count(iStockID) Count
     from   
         _etblInvJrBatchLines
     group by 
         iStockID) X)
    declare @increment int =1
while @increment <= @count 
{
-- do your insert here...
@increment = @increment +1
}
```

Do the looping in your client code.
Retrieve the count value from your initial query

```
For increment = 1 to @count
'execute SQL to do insert here...
Next increment
```

Or better (as @scsimon hinted at)...

```
For increment = 1 to @count
'build the VALUES () clauses for your insert statement...
Next
'execute your insert statement
```

I didn't realize that T-SQL allowed multiple VALUES clauses in an INSERT. Thank you @scsimon!

If it's me, I'm doing all of this in a client with code, not in the database. I'm old school, and I don't think that solutions like this scale well when built in the database as in my first example.

Comment: this would perform terribly. It's a RBAR operation which isn't how SQL is developed.  Just a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your contribution!

Special thanks to @Thomas as his advice worked the best in my environment.

I altered his script a little bit to accommodate the reference numbering:

```
declare @count int

 set @count = (select
    max(count) Max
from
    (select 
         count(iStockID) Count
     from   
         _etblInvJrBatchLines
     group by 
         iStockID) X) --Hardcoded 10
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tally') IS NOT NULL
  /*Then it exists*/
  DROP TABLE #tally
SELECT TOP (@count) --equates to more than 30 years of dates
        IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS N
   INTO #tally
   FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns sc1,
        Master.dbo.SysColumns sc2

--PRINT @count
INSERT INTO  _etblInvJrBatches 
(
    cInvJrNumber            --  IJ0001
,   cInvJrDescription       --  Inventory Journal Batch
,   cInvJrReference         --  IJR10001
,   iCreateAgentID          --  1
,   bClearAfterPost         --  1
,   bAllowDupRef            --  1
,   bAllowEditGLContra      --  0
,   iNewLineDateOpt         --  0
,   iNewLineRefOpt          --  0
,   cNewLineRefDef          --  ''
,   bNewLineRefInc          --  0
,   iNewLineDescOpt         --  0
,   cNewLineDescDef         --  ''
,   bNewLineDescInc         --  0
,   iNewLineProjectOpt      --  0
,   iNewLineProjectDefID    --  0
,   iNewLineWarehouseOpt    --  0
,   iNewLineWarehouseDefID  --  0
,   bJustCleared            --  0
,   iTransactionCode        --  31 (select idTrCodes from TrCodes where Code = 'ADJ')
)

select
    'IJ000' + cast(N as varchar)
,   'Inventory Journal Batch'
,   'IJR1000' + cast(N as varchar)
,   1
,   1
,   1
,   0
,   0
,   0
,   ''
,   0
,   0
,   ''
,   0
,   0
,   0
,   0
,   0
,   0
,   (select idTrCodes from TrCodes where Code = 'ADJ')
from #tally where n >0 and n <= @count
```

**This worked like a charm!**

See results:[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ODVL.png)